# cannot compile nano from source

Tags: compiling, nano

i am trying to build nano from source, but the installation guide doesn't make any sense.
it says to run `./configure` but there isn't any `configure` file, and even in some of the repository it is in, it doesn't do anything.

i am on Ubuntu server 22.04.2 LTS if that helps

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us something to go on. First, what source? Where did you get it from? Where can we get it from? What installation guide? Where can we see that? We can't help you if you don't tell us what you are actually doing.

Comment: Most likely the source is the [official build guide](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/nano.git/tree/README.hacking).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is actually very easy, just read the [compile instruction](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/nano.git/tree/README.hacking?h=v7.2) in the repository. Lets assume, you want to compile the latest version `v7.2` yourself.

1. Enable jammy sources for `apt` and update the repositories

   ```
   $ sudo bash -c 'echo "deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jammy_sources.list'
   $ sudo apt update
   ```
2. Install all build dependencies from Ubuntu for nano

   ```
   $ sudo apt build-dep nano -y
   ```
3. Install `git` for cloning the nano repo and `checkinstall` for easy Debian package generation.

   ```
   $ apt install git checkinstall -y
   ```
4. Clone, checkout v7.2, generate autotools files, configure and build nano

   ```
   $ git clone https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/nano.git
   $ cd nano
   $ git checkout v7.2
   $ ./autogen.sh
   $ ./configure
   $ make -j$(nproc)
   ```
5. Finally install the package with `checkinstall`. Since Ubuntu has already a `nano` package, we will call the package `mynano` to avoid conflicts.

   ```
   $ sudo checkinstall -D -y --pkgname=mynano
   ```

That's it. Now you will find nano in `/usr/loca/bin/nano` Therefore it will not damage the original nano package and due to the execution order in the `$PATH`, it will be called, even if the normal nano package is installed.

If you want or need to remove your self build nano, just call:

```
$ sudo dpkg -r mynano
```